# python subprocess check_output

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I am try to execute below command using python subprocess but it is failing.

Please help

```
  import subprocess
  cmd = "bash /opt/health_check -t 2>/dev/null"
  retcode = subprocess.call([cmd])
  print retcode
```

I am getting below output:

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./script.py", line 65, in <module>
    retcode = subprocess.call([cmd])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call `check_output` with a *list*, you would need to tokenize the command yourself, as in:

```
import subprocess
cmd = ["bash", "/opt/health_check", "-t"]
retcode = subprocess.call([cmd])
print retcode
```

This doesn't use a shell so you can't use input redirection.  If you really want to execute your command with a shell, then pass a *string* and set `shell=True`:

```
import subprocess
cmd = "bash /opt/health_check -t 2>/dev/null"
retcode = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
print retcode
```

Comment: Or start with a list before hand, or trying using  `shlex.split()` on the string first...

Answer (score 0):

This is an incorrect way to call `subprocess`. A quick and dirty way to do it is to change it like:

```
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

This will invoke the system's shell to execute the command, and you'll have access to all the goodies it provides. It's not something to use ligthly, however, so check [security considerations](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations) from the docs before doing so.

Otherwise, you can simply provide the command as a list, like so:

```
subprocess.call(["bash", "/opt/health_check"])
```